# How to specifiy library search path with clang

Tags: gcc, clang

With gcc, you can use the -L option to point to additional library directories. I can't find that option in th manpages in clang. How do we do this? I did find the -I for the include files directories however.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just -L, the Clang man pages are apparently still horridly incomplete.